# pass data from controller to view with laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

i have a controller with a methode that list me all the files in a directory. the problem is that i have to return a list that contain the files and now it returns only the first file.

```
public function getafficher()
{
    $dirname = 'directory'; 
    $dir = opendir($dirname); 

        while($file = readdir($dir)) { 
        if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && !is_dir($dirname.$file)) { 
            $data1 = "$file";
            list($num,$nom,$marque,$couleur) = explode("_", $data1);


            return view('page.afficherData')-> withNum($num)
                                          -> withNom($nom)
                                          -> withMarque($marque)
                                          -> withCouleur($couleur)
                                          ;
                   }

               } 


            closedir($dir); 

}
```

is there another way to do this? should i make a loop in my blade?

Comment: you are returning instantly in your while loop. Try to put the view result into an array and after the loop output it with `implode`

Comment: i've triyed something like this :  $this->data =array($num,$nom, .......); and i put the return statement in the end with this : return view('page.afficherData',$this->data); but it doesn't work